# Cross-provider video search on XBox 360

Tags: xbox-360

I'm considering getting an XBox 360, but as I read about the [dozens of video-content providers](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/live/partners) that have been jumping on board over the last few years, I wonder about content silos.

Does the XBox have any kind of search that will find specific video content wherever it is (Netflix, Hulu Plus, HBOGo, Paramount, etc.) or do I have to go into each app, do a search, not find what I'm looking for, back out, go into the next one, rinse and repeat?

Because that's a big pile of suck.

(Originally [posted on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/436947/cross-provider-video-search-on-xbox-360))

Comment: Pretty sure that your assumption that it doesn't search all of them is correct, but I'd have to test when I get home. There is a search on the Dashboard, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't search through content in the Netflix and Amazon Video apps that I have.

Comment: @DoozerBlake: yeah, the consensus around the web seems to be that it doesn't, but I'm still interested in confirmation.  I may be asking for what Google TV was intended to be, but we saw how well that worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had assumed that you were correct in that it doesn't search across all providers, but a quick test proves that I am wrong.

You can use the Bing search (left-most screen on the dashboard) to search video content across all the current video providers.

I did a quick test using *Arrested Development* as a query knowing that it existed in both Netflix and Amazon Instant Video, which I have installed. Results came up for Arrested Development, however, you have to click through first to the show, second to the season, third to the episode, where it will finally tell you where you can play it from. The results themselves include providers that you have installed, and ones that you may not. In this case, it has results for: Zune, Netflix, Hulu Plus, Amazon Instant Video, and Vudu. If you click through on the provider, it will load the video or imformation page in the selected app (tested only with Netflix and Amazon Instant Video).

Comment: That's awesome!  Thank you so much for trying it out.

Comment: @DavidRubin Yeah, I was pleasantly surprised. The interface could use some adjustment, lots of clicks to get there, but still nice to have. I'm assuming they maybe make it a requirement of the providers to provider their results to the main search.